# How to transfer JTextField input to a JTextArea using a variable?

Tags: java, swing

Before I begin, I want to say I've looked into the other similar questions, but they didn't answer my problem.

Hi all,
I'm trying to make a Swing programme that takes the text entered in the  JTextField (variable name: input), and put that text in the JTextArea (variable name: output) by using the "String reversedText" to store the JTextField's text. I want it to transfer the text once I press the "Reverse!" button (variable name: reverseButton).

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();//creating instance of JFrame

JLabel text = new JLabel("Enter some text to be reversed:");
static JTextField input = new JTextField();
static JTextArea output = new JTextArea();
JButton reverseButton = new JButton("Reverse!");

String reveresedText = "";
```

As you can see below, I tried using an actionListener to do so, but nothing happens when I press the "Reverse!" button.

```
public Main(){

    setBounds();
    setButtonAction();

    f.add(text);
    f.add(input);

    f.add(output);
    output.setEditable(false);

    f.add(reverseButton);

    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    refreshText();
}

private void setButtonAction(){
    reverseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            reveresedText = input.getText();
        }
    });
}

private void refreshText() {
    output.setText(reveresedText);

    f.repaint();
}
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the text directly to the JTextArea;

```
private void setButtonAction(){
    reverseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String txt = new StringBuilder(input.getText()).reverse().toString();
            output.append(txt);
        }
    });
}
```